# Cannot allocate memory - FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video, concatenation

While giving effects to multiple video using FFMPEG. I am getting error Error while filtering: Cannot allocate memoryme=00:06:02.98 bitrate= 676.0kbits/s dup=22 drop=0 speed=4.58x Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0

Logs are available at url: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Ulq_muQlHbu3q25ciDRge5tlx9jOZ0N/view?usp=sharing

Script below:

```
ffmpeg -i Episode10_2952.mp4 -i Episode10_3507.mp4 -i Episode10_RmvAdVi_1_5645.mp4 -i Episode10_RmvAdVi_1_9226.mp4 -i Episode10_3507-5.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=8.07[V01]; \
 [V01][2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=16.81[V02]; \
 [V02][3]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=16.58[V03]; \
 [V03][4]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=26.42,format=yuv420p[video]; \
 [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A01]; \
 [A01][2:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A02]; \
 [A02][3:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A03]; \
 [A03][4:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" \
-map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

[Calculating Offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56VM6.png)

Comment: Lazy suggestion is to [download a more recent ffmpeg](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/) and try again. If it works either an old bug was fixed, or there was something wrong with your ffmpeg build.

Comment: Many thanks for this.

Now the error has gone and video is produced with no issues.

But there are following issues:

1.) Video size is 09:50
2.) Audio of video is completlty out of sync
3.) I am not seeing any effect produced


logs are available here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gBO5te4t3Kdum-OIimHKhHjvWRXsfogq/view?usp=sharing

Please advise.

Kind Regards,

Comment: I answered the original "Cannot allocate memory" question, so that is solved. I recommend asking a new question because these are new, separate issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ffmpeg` is too old. [Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) a new version and the message will go away.

Comment: Thanks, I have downloaded the latest version only today and tried from there.

D:\ffmpeg\bin>ffmpeg
ffmpeg version 2021-05-09-git-8649f5dca6-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev6, Built by MSYS2 project)

Comment: I agree with you that this question is solved. I will open another question for this. Many thanks for your great support.

Comment: As advised, opened another question here https://superuser.com/questions/1648563/issue-in-video-when-giving-effects-to-multiple-videos-using-ffmpeg