# Issue in Video when giving effects to multiple videos using FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, concatenation

I am facing issue when giving effects to multiple video using FFMPEG using script below:

```
ffmpeg -i Episode10_2952.mp4 -i Episode10_3507.mp4 -i Episode10_RmvAdVi_1_5645.mp4 -i Episode10_RmvAdVi_1_9226.mp4 -i Episode10_3507-5.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0][1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=8.07[V01]; \
 [V01][2]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=16.81[V02]; \
 [V02][3]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=16.58[V03]; \
 [V03][4]xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.5:offset=26.42,format=yuv420p[video]; \
 [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A01]; \
 [A01][2:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A02]; \
 [A02][3:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[A03]; \
 [A03][4:a]acrossfade=d=0.5:c1=tri:c2=tri[audio]" \
-map "[video]" -map "[audio]" -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

I am facing following issues:

1.) Video size is 09:50
2.) Audio of video is completlty out of sync
3.) I am not seeing any effect produced

Logs are available here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yhXTyFpiqm05i2Ox2WgCtmNA8akwAuMQ/view?usp=sharing

FFmpeg version details are available here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JLuwJRrtsgtmGLuSj3oQUYWJvkZBu8gn/view?usp=sharing

Offset value coming for 3rd video is 16.58, which is less than second one. Is this ok? If not what is the solution in this case?

Also, I have used bigger image inspite of this video. Still I am facing the issue I mentioned.

Please advise.

Video duration and offset calculation below:
[Offset calculation here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1Y8t.png)

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inputs are minutes long, but your xfade offsets are just seconds long.

For example, your first xfade should be `offset=537.07` or `offset=00\\\:08\\\:57.07`.

Comment: Many Many thanks for your great help. You are genius. I will convert into the programe and let you know if any issues.

Comment: Hi llogan, I tried with my program and it is giving me error. See if you can help me in question: https://superuser.com/questions/1650734/error-while-filtering-cannot-allocate-memory-ffmpeg Many Thanks